# ios how can access and modify variable from diffent class?

Tags: iphone, ios, properties, uiviewcontroller

I have the following:

```
Class 1:

.h file:
@interface class1 : UIViewController

@property (assign,nonatomic) int number;

.m file:

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
number=1;
}

Class2:

.h file:
@interface class2 : UIView{
    class1 *Controller;
}

@property (retain,nonatomic) class1 *controller;
```

but if access the number variable from anywhere in the second class the value is 0 any of you knows why?

Comment: Did `viewDidLoad` get called? Did you instantiate the controller property in your `class2` instance? Also, please read up on Objective-C naming conventions, it will make your code easier to read and help us help you easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the class already open and retained somewhere (i.e. your navigation stack)?  If so you can then safely access and modify variables because they are already initialized.  If not that's probably why you're getting 0 returned.

Another way is to create and maintain a data singleton that all view controllers can draw data from easily and you can then reference that data singleton to modify and change values.

Assuming the view controller is already initialized and active you can then do something like this:

```
MyViewController *vc = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
[vc setValue:@"100"];
```

Comment: won't that initialize it again? I'm wanting to edit a value in the onboarding process of the app then set it to a new value that will persist after onboarding is done. Would you recommend a singleton, delegate, or notification??

Answer (score 0):

You can use appDelegate method to access the variable from some other class,

example,

in your class2:
.m file

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{

    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
        Controller = appDelegate.viewControllerClass1;
    }
    return self;
}
```

in AppDelegate Class, .m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.viewControllerClass1 = [[[Class1 alloc] init] autorelease];
    NavigationController=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:self.viewControllerClass1];

 [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```